# Before going to kernel in Intel GPU some user defined data is printed on the command prompt or in the text file

Tags: opencl, intel

I have been working on Open Cl C++ for last few months on Intel GPU. I put the break points at the `__kernel` function. Breakpoints are working fine but print functions inside the kernel functions are executed even though the breakpoints are present in the kernel function. I have tried the same example on AMD it is working perfectly. In Intel, why is the data printed even though I have set a breakpoint in the Kernel.

Here's an example:

```
// at kernel side code 
__kernel void hello()
{
    print("hello\n"); ---> Line 1
    print("hi\n"); ---> Line 2
}
```

I included breakpoints at line 1 on Intel GPU. When I started observing the command prompt or a text file, it will print the data two to three times or sometimes more than three times. Can someone help me as to why the data is being printed even after adding a breakpoint in my Kernel Function.
Thanks in advance for any help on this issue.

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language; pick one.

Comment: at present i am working on opencl c++